# Does Bugzilla support integration into subversion?

Tags: svn, bugzilla

I noticed that they have a list of plugins here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons#Integration_with_Source_Code_Management_programs

...But most of those seem either outdated or barely above a simple utility/script as opposed to actual "scm *integration*". Anyone here use SVN along with Bugzilla here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want SCMBug and possibly also the "VCS" extension. (I believe both are listed on http://wiki.mozilla.org/Bugzilla:Addons.)

Answer (score 0):

What capabilities do you require that something like scmbug doesn't do?  I'm not really certain what you expect integration to really mean.

I think generic integration solutions are less important now because of the hooking capabilities of both Subversion and Bugzilla.  Using Bugzilla's web services, you could add a pre-commit hook that communicates with Bugzilla and decides whether to let the commit proceed.  You could add a post-commit hook that updates something in Bugzilla to show the commit.  You could add an extension to Bugzilla to do whatever in Subversion when a bug has been resolved, but that strikes me as being a dicey proposition.